# To add an indicator variable to a data frame

Tags: r, tidyverse

I wanted to add a new column called "Missing" to  `penguins` data frame, so for any rows with at least an `NA`, I want to have `TRUE` in the `Missing` column and `FALSE` otherwise. My code just added all `FALSE` to the new column. How do I fix this? Thank you.

```
## install.packages("palmerpenguins")
library(palmerpenguins)
View(penguins)
penguins_m <- penguins %>%
  mutate(Missing = ifelse(is.na(.),T,F))


  species island bill_length_mm bill_depth_mm flipper_length_… body_mass_g sex    year Missing[,"speci… [,"island"] [,"bill_length_… [,"bill_depth_m…
  <fct>   <fct>           <dbl>         <dbl>            <int>       <int> <fct> <int> <lgl>            <lgl>       <lgl>            <lgl>           
1 Adelie  Torge…           39.1          18.7              181        3750 male   2007 FALSE            FALSE       FALSE            FALSE           
2 Adelie  Torge…           39.5          17.4              186        3800 fema…  2007 FALSE            FALSE       FALSE            FALSE           
3 Adelie  Torge…           40.3          18                195        3250 fema…  2007 FALSE            FALSE       FALSE            FALSE           
4 Adelie  Torge…           NA            NA                 NA          NA NA     2007 FALSE            FALSE       TRUE             TRUE            
5 Adelie  Torge…           36.7          19.3              193        3450 fema…  2007 FALSE            FALSE       FALSE            FALSE           
6 Adelie  Torge…           39.3          20.6              190        3650 male   2007 FALSE            FALSE       FALSE            FALSE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what the `complete.cases` function does, so you can do

```
penguins_m <- penguins %>%
  mutate(Missing = !complete.cases(.))
```

A couple comments on your attempt - when you have a function or test that returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`, you don't need to wrap it in `ifelse` to get a TRUE/FALSE result.

Your attempt doesn't work because `is.na(x)` doesn't return 1 value per row if `x` is a data frame - it actually returns a matrix of TRUE/FALSE values showing whether each individual value is missing or not. So, if we didn't know about `complete.cases` we could use it like this:

```
penguins_m <- penguins %>%
  mutate(Missing = rowSums(is.na(.)) > 0)
```